# FTPS login succeeds but put fails

Tags: php, ftp, ftps, passive-mode

Since I lost a half day solving this, I believe this is worth sharing my issue (and solution) here.

Here is my initial code:

```php
$host = ...
$user = ...
$pass = ...
$conn = ftp_ssl_connect($host, 22);
if($conn === false) {
    die('could not connect :(');
}

$login_result = ftp_login($conn, $user, $pass);
ftp_pasv($conn, true);
$file = realpath('test.txt');
echo 'putting file '.$file."\n";
ftp_put($conn, 'test.txt', $file, FTP_BINARY);
ftp_close($conn);
```

Unfortunately, this did not work, even if the connection succeeds. Here is the message I got from the fpt_put line after hanging for roughly one minute:

> Warning: ftp_put(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (36)

Note that this is not a passive toggle issue (I tried with and without), as I could see in most similar issues.

N.B.: I know that usually port 21 is used, but when you are working with 3rd parties, you may not have any choice.

Comment: Your question is not about SFTP (over SSH), but about FTPS (FTP over TLS/SSL).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl If you feel that that is what the question is about, then the related tag should be added and removing the one that doesn't belong.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl you are completely right! I edited to reflect this...

Answer (score 2):

So here is the solution and a big thanks to this blog post: http://www.elitehosts.com/blog/php-ftp-passive-ftp-server-behind-nat-nightmare/ which showed me the right way...

Basically, it looks like the fix has been added to PHP and the FTP_USEPASVADDRESS option does the trick, that is, set the option right before switching to passive mode:

```php
$host = ...
$user = ...
$pass = ...
$conn = ftp_ssl_connect($host, 22);
if($conn === false) {
    die('could not connect :(');
}

$login_result = ftp_login($conn, $user, $pass);
//ADD THIS ⬇︎
ftp_set_option($conn, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false);
//ADD THIS ⬆︎
ftp_pasv($conn, true);
$file = realpath('test.txt');
echo 'putting file '.$file."\n";
ftp_put($conn, 'test.txt', $file, FTP_BINARY);
ftp_close($conn);
```

And this works :D.
Hope this will help someone...

Comment: For me, it doesn't work